# Other means of payment related to property taxes

Tags: tax-law

Probably my question is related to one of my previous ones, but it is most likely not the same.
If a foreigner who doesn't live in the US as main residence and therefore doesn't have tax residence there (i.e he's not liable to US income taxes) own a house in NYC, can he receive property taxes bills (or demands of payment or any technicay fitting name) via mail and then pay them via banking, or home banking in case he cannot pay them in the US?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about bureaucratic financial procedure, not the law or legal process.

Answer (score 2):

> If a foreigner who doesn't live in the US as main residence and
>   therefore doesn't have tax residence there (i.e he's not liable to US
>   income taxes) own a house in NYC, can he receive property taxes bills
>   (or demands of payment or any technicay fitting name) via mail and
>   then pay them via banking, or home banking in case he cannot pay them
>   in the US?

Yes. And, the foreign has a strong incentive to do so, because even if the foreigner has no other U.S. assets, the unpaid taxes would become a first priority lien against the property and allow the property to be seized for non-payment of taxes even if the unpaid taxes are worth much less than the property.

There are many ways that this can be arranged.